# Books Recommendation: 20th Century Music

Tags: history, rock

I was looking for books that discuss the evolution of music in the 20th century, especially the second half.

If it's a book about the history of Rock & Roll, that's fine too.

Hopefully something that talks about the various bands and genres that formed and evolved from 1950's till the end of the 1990's.

It doesn't have to be a book, it can be a website as well. I was thinking of something like **A History of Rock and Dance Music** by Scaruffi. I would read that one, but some of the reviews about it were very discouraging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're more concerned with the so called "classical" ("erudite", "non-vernacular") type of music in the 20th century, the most obvious resource would be Alex Ross' book "The Rest His Noise".

Regarding the history of rock, there is a on line free course from Coursera, [History of Rock](https://www.coursera.org/learn/history-of-rock), that may fit your expectations. It's devided in two parts, check the courses syllabuses to see which one interests you the most, or both.

The teacher of this course, [John Covach](https://www.coursera.org/instructor/johncovach), has also other courses, specifically about the Beatles and the Rolling Stones, and a number of published books, among which [What's that Sound](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393937259) seems to fit what you're looking for too. But I have not read that book personally, so I'm not specifically recommendig it. I can say, however, that his courses in Coursera are very thorough and interesting and the prof. is indeed very knowledgeable, an authority in fact, about the history of rock.

Comment: Yes! That two part coursera course looks amazing and is just what I'm looking for! Thanks.